# Update an Excel component in Word without opening the component

Tags: excel, ms-word

How to update an Excel component in a Word document without opening the component? Can I add some VBA code in my Word document to achieve this? Ideally, the update could be done when I open the Word document every time.

Answer (score 0):

What is a component in your world?

A Word document can contain Excel charts or tables that are linked to Excel files. When the Word document is opened, the link(s) to the Excel file(s) will refresh automatically. If the Excel data has changed since the last time the Word document was opened, that change will now be visible in Word.

To create a linked table or chart, copy the data/chart in Excel, then paste it in Word and in the dialog select the radio button to "Paste Link"

Select and copy the Excel table

[image]

Paste into Word with Paste Special and tick "Paste Link"

[image]

The result in Word looks like this and will update the Excel table whenever the Excel table changes.

[image]

All this happens without employing any VBA. It's basic out of the box Office functionality.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, I have this object. My question is how to update this object, which is in a word doc, without right click and open it. I have many this type of objects in a report (word doc). They contain real time data. However,  now I need to open them one by one to update them. Otherwise they will only show as a static picture.

Comment: "This object". Really? I still don't know if you mean a code object or a square of information in a Word file. Microsoft Office comes with built-in integration features to show Excel tables or charts in Word or to show Word documents in Excel tables. I showed you how to create an integrated Excel table in a Word file. The Excel table will update when the Word file is opened. What is your problem?